# how to get notification count of google phone and message app?

Tags: android

Xiaomi phones with Global MIUI ROM come with the Google phone and Messages app. These apps have ugly icons and don't follow theme icons. I have created empty apps with the package name `com.android.mms`, `com.android.contacts`, `com.android.cantacts.activity.twelvekeydialer`. these apps are empty and just launch their Google counterparts. now these apps follow theme icons and are beautiful. the problem is that they don't show the notification count of the original apps.

how i can get the notification count of Google contacts and Google messages apps and show them on my shortcut apps? I only need to get new messages count and missed call count.

I have zero knowledge about Android development and that shortcuts took a day for me to get a minified build. please explain for a backend developer without any mobile development experience!